# How do I publish my file from Remix IDE to IPFS?

Tags: ide, localhost, ethereum, ipfs, remix

So i'm using remix IDE for my project and i only have one single file named crop.sol
I have uploaded it to ipfs using ipfs add -r *filename*
and i have ipfs daemon on a seperate terminal active and it says its ready

the webui of ipfs(where i can see my file) is http://localhost:5001/ipfs/bafybeifeqt7mvxaniphyu2i3qhovjaf3sayooxbh5enfdqtiehxjv2ldte/#/

now after i compile crop.sol on remix IDE , I click on Publish to IPFS but it shows the following error message.
Failed to publish metadata file and sources to ipfs, please check the ipfs gateways is available.
Error: HTTPError: project id required

What do I do?

under ipfs settings on remix IDE there are 5 fields and i have filled them as below :
ipfs host : EMPTY
ipfs protocol : EMPTY
ipfs port : 5001
ipfs project ID(Infura) : EMPTY
ipfs project secret(Infura) : EMPTY